Forward costs without taxing it?
Alice does private gigs with a crew in Germany and usually issues a "Honorar Rechnung" (fee invoice) for doing so. These are usually below the allowed amount (600-750€/year) where no tax needs to be paid.
Alice does a special gig in Austria which had a lot of logistics and material costs. The venue was willing to pay for it, but Alice had to pay in advance and the venue wants an invoice.
Can Alice write something like an invoice that actually just forwards the cost so that Alice does not have to pay taxes (income tax) on it?
After all, it is not profit for Alice.

This question will likely get closed for asking for legal advice. I'll edit it to make it more generic. Feel free to roll back if you don't like the changes.

What tax are you talking about? Is it VAT? or income tax? Or anything else?

Probably Mehrwehrtsteuer, VAT, which also differs for germany and austria and this triggers several cross-border problems...

maybe it isn't, but this sounds like how to scam the tax man

@TigerGuy :-D
No, i just don't want to pay income tax when nobody makes a profit.
I do the gig for fun, the venue is willing to pay for logistics and accommodation. No Profit made on my side.
That's why i thought i should not pay taxes for this.

england-and-wales
You can't invent the facts to suit your preferred tax outcome. You need to look at what the actual contractual arrangements were. For example, they might have been one of the following:

Alice contracted with the venue to provide a gig for a fee of £5000. In turn, Alice contracted with various suppliers for goods/services costing £4500 which Alice needed in order to be able to provide the gig.

Alice acted as the venue's agent for the purpose of arranging for the venue to contract with various suppliers for goods/services costing £4500 that it needed in order to host the gig. In addition, Alice contracted with the venue to provide the gig itself for a fee of £500.


Which of these is applicable will depend on all of the facts and circumstances of Alice's arrangement with the venue. You would need to look at what was said, what was written down (including a written contract if any), who the third party suppliers believed they were dealing with, what names were written on the invoices, etc. Things can get complicated if for example Alice was acting as the venue's agent but didn't tell the third party supplier about this and so they thought they were contracting with Alice.
In scenario 1, Alice would need to account for tax on the basis of income of £5000 and costs of £4500 (leaving a profit of £500). In scenario 2 Alice would need to account for tax on the basis of income of £500 and the venue would need to account for the £4500.
